# Why do we get fewer characters in custom mod flags on comments than on posts?

Tags: discussion, flags, comment-flags

I recently went to raise a custom mod flag on a troublesome comment, and found myself running up against the character limit. I thought that I had raised custom flags with much longer comments before, and a quick experiment revealed that comments in custom mod flags on questions and answers get to be 300 characters longer than comments in custom mod flags on comments.

Custom mod flag for comments
[image: Custom mod flag for comments]

Custom mod flag for posts
[image: Custom mod flag for posts]

**Why is the maximum length so much shorter when custom mod flagging a comment?**

Comment: the backing field in the database doesn't allow for more characters and no-one bothered to make that field bigger.

Comment: @AnnDaunted, Sometimes it's necessary to link to prior comments and flags, we don't what a couple of links to cause a terse message; so it's good to have the fields sufficiently long.

Comment: In 2011 the character limit on custom flags for posts was raised by Jeff Atwood from 150 to 500. He probably just forgot to do the same for comments (or didn't think it necessary).