# Can we get a longer maximum length for messages in custom mod flags on comments?

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags

Back in May I posted [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327997/316226) when I noticed that we have a 200 character limit for messages in custom mod flags on comments, but a 500 character limit for messages in custom mod flags on posts.

Custom mod flag for comments
[image: Custom mod flag for comments]

Custom mod flag for posts
[image: Custom mod flag for posts]

Since that time, I've had a few instances where I've needed to write a somewhat verbose message in the custom mod flag for a comment. The most common case of this is when asking for the deletion of a long thread of comments that are no longer needed. In that case I usually end up switching my flag to the post and providing the needed context there, but as Rob pointed out in a comment on my original question

> Sometimes it's necessary to link to prior comments and flags, we don't what a couple of links to cause a terse message

It's less work for both the flagger and the moderator handling the flag if you can flag the comment in need of moderation instead of flagging the post and having to tell the mod what comment you are referring to. That is why I am proposing that the character limit for messages on custom mod flags cast on comments be lengthened to match that of the custom mod flag message for posts.

I'm aware of [this previous request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303444/316226) which was made several years ago and never received an official response. With that post being so old, it can't account for the current atmosphere of SE where comment flags might need more attention and detail, so I think there is merit for a new question on this topic.

Comment: Looks like a dupe of [Make the moderator flag comment max length longer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303444/232439). You may avoid having this one closed if you reference the dupe in your question and make it clear it was a few years ago, never received community consensus and that comment flags need more attention given the current SE atmosphere.

Comment: A useful alternative implementation is: Instead of "increasing the length", make links count as 10 characters (up to a limit of 1023? characters of *real* length); that would allow a few questions with long titles or a couple of *crazy long* Google URLs - ***but*** if your message is solely textual then rambling on would be prevented.

Comment: I don't see any upside. I'd rather handle three *no longer needed* than reading through detective novels in comment flags.

Comment: @Helmar Sure that works in the case of cleaning up a thread of comments that have served their purpose, but there are other cases where a greater explanation is needed. It could be that you've noticed a pattern of behavior by a user in comments and you need to link to a few of them to paint the right picture for the mods. We had a case on IPS a few months back where a user who had never posted a question or answer was serial posting comments and the community was having trouble keeping up with flagging them all. Much easier to point a mod to a few of the comments than to make them go looking.

Comment: @Rainbacon just flag them all.