# How to "Be precise" without explaining anything

Tags: feature-request, flags, character-limit

I just flagged a post for custom moderator intervention and I was asked to be precise and detailed in my explanation.

And then the box ended with like two tweets length. Seriously? I should be precise and you try to save on database bytes?

Can you please give a little more room there?

I'm supposed to explain something to someone in detail and after pasting the URL in question, I get fewer characters left than a regular comment.

Not cool. Not for me. Not for the poor person who has to make sense of it on the other end either.

**Please make the custom flag reason a length where you can actually reason.**

Comment: If you disagree, feel free to leave an answer or comment with a reason, why it is better to keep it that short. Maybe it does make sense, and I just don't see it.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327997/why-do-we-get-fewer-characters-in-custom-mod-flags-on-comments-than-on-posts

Comment: On all the flags I raised I only recall two or three times where I had to seriously re-edit and leave things out that I felt were needed for context. I assume those handling your flag are able to make the same mental leap you made even if you provide them with incomplete info. In my case the flags were marked helpful. Is this  a limit you hit regularly? maybe a CM can run a query to see how many flags are near the allowed max length.

Comment: What *is* the (current) actual custom flag reason text length (to be precise)? You may link to a post on this site.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q max length is 500 on post flags, 200 on comment flags.

Answer (score 13):

While I agree the character limit should be increased (a bit; we don't want walls of text there), please note that you can shorten the URLs, e.g. [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356382/how-to-be-precise-without-explaining-anything`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356382/how-to-be-precise-without-explaining-anything) can be shortened to [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356382`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356382) or even shorter: [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356382`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356382). The 'share' link underneath each post uses the last, short form too (but appends your user ID). I regularly link to three or more posts in a custom flag, and there's room for a sentence or two as well.

If you feel you do need to share more information, consider asking the moderators to create a [private chatroom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143645/295232), where there's also more room for interaction.